# Dynamic table view cell wrong height when using >= constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have cells with dynamic height inside an UITableView.
In interface builder, everything looks good.
These are my constraints:

[image]
[image]

But on the device, there is added empty space at the top and bottom of some messages. There would be no problem if the label's `greater than or equal` constraint would be an `equality` constraint, but the bubbles have the width of the screen.

[image]

This is my cell configuration:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceivedMessage") as! MessageTableViewCell
            cell.messageLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.setNeedsDisplay()
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SentMessage") as! MessageTableViewCell
            cell.messageLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.setNeedsDisplay()
            return cell
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Try to increase label's content hugging priority.

Comment: @DanKarbayev nothing changes.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with cells that have `"ReceivedMessage"` as the `reuseIdentifier`, but you are showing the constraints for the cells that have `"SentMessage"` as the `reuseIdentifier`. You also likely want the top constraint of your "Sent message text" label to have priority of 999 so it will break without warning when the label's height is less than the image view's.

Comment: @beyowulf Hi. The problem also appears on "SentMessage" cells. "SentMessage" is the same as "ReceivedMessage", but mirrored. If I change the `if indexPath.row % 2 == 0` condition to `if indexPath.row % 2 == 1`, I would have the same problem, but with "SentMessage" cells. I changed the top constraint's priority but the main problem is still there.